# Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial on Ubuntu 64 in VMPlayer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, heroku

I am working through chapter 1 of the Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial I first ran into trouble when I tried to use Git but that was because I hadn't made the SSH Keys. I have that working but next got stuck on trying to add keys to Heroku. I think it should just be able to save using the same keys. This is what I am getting and I can't figure out what the error is telling me. I am totally new to Ruby and Rails.

```
    bill44077@ubuntu:~/Sites/rails_projects/first_app$ heroku keys:add
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.17.10/lib/heroku/commands/app.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.17.10/lib/heroku/command.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.17.10/lib/heroku/command.rb:5:in `each'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.17.10/lib/heroku/command.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.17.10/bin/heroku:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
bill44077@ubuntu:~/Sites/rails_projects/first_app$ heroku keys:add
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.17.10/lib/heroku/commands/app.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.17.10/lib/heroku/command.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.17.10/lib/heroku/command.rb:5:in `each'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.17.10/lib/heroku/command.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-1.17.10/bin/heroku:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /home/bill44077/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

Sorry - I couldn't figure out how to get this to put in line feeds.

Thanks for any help!
Bill44077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your ruby has not been compiled with readline and looking at your ruby path ... you're using RVM. 
Look at this documentation :

http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/

basically you'll need to reinstall your ruby with readline (--with-readline-dir). 
Don't forget to look at the other rvm options before installing your ruby so you wont have to reinstall it again if you need iconv, zlib or X).

By the way if you don't have readline your rails console should not work and you're in the process of deploying so I'd say ... you should use your rails console more often :-)

Enjoy !

Comment: Thanks Mike! I'll give it a try when I get home tonight (.net by day, ruby by night :)